# Adding multiple files to Hadoop distributed cache?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to add multiple files to hadoop distributed cache. Actually I don't know the file names. They will be named like `part-0000*`. Can someone tell me how to do that?

Thanks
Bala

Answer (score 2):

You can use either the hadoop -put or -copyFromLocal command:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hadoop/outgoing/* /your/hadoop/dir
```

Comment: You could either write bash scripts and call them from Java, or look at the HDFS Java API - see "Using HDFS Programmatically" - http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module2.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem although it maybe a bit late:

```
FileSystem fs = directoryPath.getFileSystem(getConf());
FileStatus[] fileStatus = fs.listStatus(directoryPath);
for (FileStatus status : fileStatus) {
    DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(status.getPath(), conf);
}
```

Is this what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from programmatically getting the list of files if they all are in one directory and the adding them one by one, right? Or is your case different?